# How to automatically click OK in response to "<app> would like to use your current location" while testing with KIF?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, kif-framework

I'm using KIF for GUI testing, and it seems we have no way in Simulator to automatically click the OK button in the `<app> would like to use your current location` alert that appears when the app is run for the first time. Is there a way to configure the Simulator or the app to get around that popup?

Answer (score 3):

A [recent addition](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/commit/a57ee3519585c94cc97bfdd9446e9eee84835a3c) to KIF adds `-acknowledgeSystemAlert` to the test runner. This can be used when running on the simulator to acknowledge location services authorization dialog. It can be used in the same way when asking for access to the user's photo library.

Comment: Any tips on how to use it? I tried     [UIAutomationHelper acknowledgeSystemAlert];     
But the alert stayed on screen - it was never dismissed. 
EDIT: I am iOS 8.3. The release notes state that it is for iOS 8.1 only. Oh well :(

Answer (score 2):

There was a [thread about this on the KIF mailing list about a year ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#%21topic/kif-framework/_MffdyvMizU).

Since you're doing this for testing only, it's easy enough to swizzle out the portions of `CLLocationManager` to avoid this alert.

(Obviously, any of this code submitted to the app store will get you rejected post haste.)

```
[CLLocationManager swizzleInstanceSelector:@selector(startUpdatingLocationFake) toSelector:@selector(startUpdatingLocation)];
[CLLocationManager swizzleInstanceSelector:@selector(locationFake) toSelector:@selector(location)];

// One for class, one for (deprecated) instance method 
[CLLocationManager swizzleInstanceSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabledFake) toSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled)];
[CLLocationManager swizzleClassSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabledFake) toSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled)];
```

where those two new class methods are defined as follows:

```
+ (void)swizzleInstanceSelector:(SEL)firstSelector toSelector:(SEL)secondSelector;
{
    Method swizzleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, firstSelector);
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(self, secondSelector);
    method_exchangeImplementations(method, swizzleMethod);
}

+ (void)swizzleClassSelector:(SEL)firstSelector toSelector:(SEL)secondSelector;
{
    Method swizzleMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, firstSelector);
    Method method = class_getClassMethod(self, secondSelector);
    method_exchangeImplementations(method, swizzleMethod);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jim, I just tried that and it doesn't work. By that I mean I added the swizzle* methods as a category onto CLLocationManager. Running the above code in my main() function did not work, nor did it work when I called it from my app delegate. Neither prevented  the pop up about "would like to use your current location”. Any other ideas? Thanks.